# Can the ASP.net login control work on iPad?

Tags: asp.net, ipad, authentication, safari

I have a .NET site and am looking to make it usable for iPad.

So far, I simply can't get the ASP.net login control to work on iPad.  The user is never classed as logged in.

It's bizarre, if they enter the wrong details the login fails. If they enter the correct details it postsback and remains displying the anonymous content, not the logged-in content.

Does anyone know what the issue is and if it can be resolved?

It works fine in Safari on a desktop, even if I use the 'develop' options to change the user agent to the iPad one. however, on iPad or iPad emulator I get the problem above.

Comment: I have the same issue except our users can't get into the textbox to type in any data.  I thought it was a cookie issue but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your Web.Config for the value of cookieless:

set it to: UseDeviceProfile and see what happens.
"
set to UseDeviceProfile to specify that the application use cookies for all browsers that support cookies. If a browser that does not support cookies accesses the site, then forms authentication packages the authentication ticket on the URL.
"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

Also what was it set to?

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
           protection="All"
           timeout="30"
           name=".ASPXAUTH" 
           path="/"
           requireSSL="false"
           slidingExpiration="true"
           defaultUrl="default.aspx"
           cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
           enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. there was no value for cookielss before or most of the other parameters you have above. i set it as above but the same occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting cookieless="UseCookies" in the  tag.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" protection="All" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

That fixed a similar iPad issue for me. I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269079/asp-net-forms-authentication-keeps-displaying-login-page).