# ASP.NET forms authentication keeps displaying login page on iPad

Tags: asp.net, ipad, forms-authentication

I have a web app which is displaying strange behaviour when used from an iPad.  On occasion, it keeps displaying the login page, even though the user gets authenticated and I create a cookie which is stored on the client.

The app is an MVC2 app, and I am calling a controller method via ajax to perform the authentication.  If the ajax call is successful then the client performs a window.location.assign() to navigate the user to the secure page.(I'm doing this to support full-screen iPad web app mode)

I use the following code to create the cookie:

```
string formsCookieStr = string.Empty;
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,                              // version
            username,                       // user name
            DateTime.Now,                   // issue time
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),    // expires
            false,                          // Persistence
            userRoleData                    // user data
    );
formsCookieStr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie FormsCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, formsCookieStr);
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(FormsCookie);
```

The url for the authentication is /Account/LogOn2.
The url that is the 'secure' page is /Admin

If I look at the IIS logs (below) then I can see that the first call to /Account/LogOn2 is passing the correct username and password.
The second log entry shows the GET that the ajax call subsequently makes, and you can clearly see that a new ASPXAUTH cookie accompanies the request - it is this cookie that was set following the first call.
Why then is the second call resulting in a 302 (redirect), when the request is properly authenticated, as proven by the presence of the ASPXAUTH cookie in the second call?  It is as if the server is not 'seeing' the authentication cookie and is forcing the 302 redirect.
The third entry shows the redirect resulting in a request for the login form again.

```
2011-06-07 16:33:37 W3SVC97442007 192.168.1.4 GET /Account/LogOn2 username=pete&password=wine&returnUrl=%2fProfileList 80 - 86.153.46.122 Mozilla/5.0+(iPad;+U;+CPU+OS+4_3_3+like+Mac+OS+X;+en-us)+AppleWebKit/533.17.9+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Mobile/8J3 .ASPXAUTH=214FCF8C485AD048B2A0833BCA77582097EBF8F88BC2B0A64D7CD4F2BD7B1D9CB0C4209DC82FFA93466A58462BCA7EAB0D35B8573CCC5AABDDD5F7ACD0D38FCCB7275A79606B990B8A189887F724BF4D30BF3F9474CCD872868FE6DB48A3825F8770116A1C142AAD99A195E5D46B7BD6DB8FCF709FDE79A6B4F70B99E9646B515946E82DD988231DCE8504E5B63134419A0A107CBB367ABC978BC71A5D7C2CEF;+ASP.NET_SessionId=5uu3m1db2iqgetgvmpjgnot2 200 0 0
2011-06-07 16:33:38 W3SVC97442007 192.168.1.4 GET /ProfileList - 80 - 86.153.46.122 Mozilla/5.0+(iPad;+U;+CPU+OS+4_3_3+like+Mac+OS+X;+en-us)+AppleWebKit/533.17.9+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Mobile/8J3 .ASPXAUTH=644A6CC55F3E1E78922FA2E5FF7E54CBF11654F636A58142C10BBD9CB8FAF440FC8A642AAE02A7A4AACC0904D27B225A38DA2016EB09AA03D761916048C35711C7AC136A9A58C63956DBCC3ABBED9EE5818F19E07585A93EB00950F53B5D3934650CFE611AAC926BC8D6BDBEE67F2EC8675ACBC66E594D0EF2556910A037E3C9782E134F56F7CAE9F9E31AD69CDB9F0C68B9B81BE7075918F9ECBC39DA03A77F;+ASP.NET_SessionId=5uu3m1db2iqgetgvmpjgnot2 302 0 0
2011-06-07 16:33:39 W3SVC97442007 192.168.1.4 GET /Account/LogOn ReturnUrl=%2fProfileList 80 - 86.153.46.122 Mozilla/5.0+(iPad;+U;+CPU+OS+4_3_3+like+Mac+OS+X;+en-us)+AppleWebKit/533.17.9+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Mobile/8J3 .ASPXAUTH=644A6CC55F3E1E78922FA2E5FF7E54CBF11654F636A58142C10BBD9CB8FAF440FC8A642AAE02A7A4AACC0904D27B225A38DA2016EB09AA03D761916048C35711C7AC136A9A58C63956DBCC3ABBED9EE5818F19E07585A93EB00950F53B5D3934650CFE611AAC926BC8D6BDBEE67F2EC8675ACBC66E594D0EF2556910A037E3C9782E134F56F7CAE9F9E31AD69CDB9F0C68B9B81BE7075918F9ECBC39DA03A77F;+ASP.NET_SessionId=5uu3m1db2iqgetgvmpjgnot2 200 0 0
2011-06-07 16:33:39 W3SVC97442007 192.168.1.4 POST /Sync/Users - 80 - 86.153.46.122 Mozilla/5.0+(iPad;+U;+CPU+OS+4_3_3+like+Mac+OS+X;+en-us)+AppleWebKit/533.17.9+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Mobile/8J3 .ASPXAUTH=644A6CC55F3E1E78922FA2E5FF7E54CBF11654F636A58142C10BBD9CB8FAF440FC8A642AAE02A7A4AACC0904D27B225A38DA2016EB09AA03D761916048C35711C7AC136A9A58C63956DBCC3ABBED9EE5818F19E07585A93EB00950F53B5D3934650CFE611AAC926BC8D6BDBEE67F2EC8675ACBC66E594D0EF2556910A037E3C9782E134F56F7CAE9F9E31AD69CDB9F0C68B9B81BE7075918F9ECBC39DA03A77F;+ASP.NET_SessionId=5uu3m1db2iqgetgvmpjgnot2 200 0 0
2011-06-07 16:33:39 W3SVC97442007 192.168.1.4 POST /Sync/Profiles - 80 - 86.153.46.122 Mozilla/5.0+(iPad;+U;+CPU+OS+4_3_3+like+Mac+OS+X;+en-us)+AppleWebKit/533.17.9+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Mobile/8J3 .ASPXAUTH=644A6CC55F3E1E78922FA2E5FF7E54CBF11654F636A58142C10BBD9CB8FAF440FC8A642AAE02A7A4AACC0904D27B225A38DA2016EB09AA03D761916048C35711C7AC136A9A58C63956DBCC3ABBED9EE5818F19E07585A93EB00950F53B5D3934650CFE611AAC926BC8D6BDBEE67F2EC8675ACBC66E594D0EF2556910A037E3C9782E134F56F7CAE9F9E31AD69CDB9F0C68B9B81BE7075918F9ECBC39DA03A77F;+ASP.NET_SessionId=5uu3m1db2iqgetgvmpjgnot2 200 0 0
```

Why is the server not 'seeing' the authentication cookie in the second request?

Thanks very much for reading this far.  I'm tearing my hair out here!

**EDIT:** thought it might be useful to show the two IIS log entries that reflect a successful login:

```
2011-06-07 17:58:08 W3SVC97442007 192.168.1.4 GET /Account/LogOn2 username=pete&password=wine&returnUrl=%2fAdmin 80 - 86.153.46.122 Mozilla/5.0+(iPad;+U;+CPU+OS+4_3_3+like+Mac+OS+X;+en-us)+AppleWebKit/533.17.9+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Mobile/8J3 - 200 0 0
2011-06-07 17:58:09 W3SVC97442007 192.168.1.4 GET /Admin - 80 - 86.153.46.122 Mozilla/5.0+(iPad;+U;+CPU+OS+4_3_3+like+Mac+OS+X;+en-us)+AppleWebKit/533.17.9+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Mobile/8J3 .ASPXAUTH=4965435E85DA486CECFAC6234F7EB96E91608374522B842642C825328E12BB199809D4982BB55AA53BBDE7123679DD48D0518AF053EE6BC5AEBE653EA922BBBFB04CCCC7E369A2C42CDBF56F63DF184DE89D74F5632C3E6F007D8852177F37482A5E48A59B39DF9F8AC8271827ED15CFB70607E8960AAFFB12433C7D9391A15B1571740F888C5654AF5F52A50D2B9E1D21682A49C4DAA24686B19F888F92C255;+ASP.NET_SessionId=0q3ah5d1rkj5drkf0clrzwdi 200 0 0
```

Note the HTTP Status code 200 for the second entry.

**EDIT** Example of successful login then client-side load of /ProfileList

```
2011-06-07 17:49:10 W3SVC97442007 192.168.1.4 GET /Account/LogOn2 username=pete&password=wine&returnUrl=%2fProfileList 80 - 86.153.46.122 Mozilla/5.0+(iPad;+U;+CPU+OS+4_3_3+like+Mac+OS+X;+en-us)+AppleWebKit/533.17.9+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Mobile/8J3 - 200 0 0
2011-06-07 17:49:13 W3SVC97442007 192.168.1.4 GET /ProfileList - 80 - 86.153.46.122 Mozilla/5.0+(iPad;+U;+CPU+OS+4_3_3+like+Mac+OS+X;+en-us)+AppleWebKit/533.17.9+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Mobile/8J3 .ASPXAUTH=26D4837E045282BF0F6118CABE52C0D1A264396BBDEE65E35502D77CD33AA39782B2F19D50971AD8C4F29BEF7DB268BF1F7359F1DBA58029C6BF1BFF6D95404B877F76D581FC8777F25030073CEB4D1ED5C591B532B41C212F772EC57717A50D063D4DAF195FCBFC4F2F6F88025043579E11D57030E6CFC51FB4250D8B3B99829E1446BD55B2C265A9153B23E2DC6D9419AA2E3E58AA01FC5760A5A7C44D69AE;+ASP.NET_SessionId=txvqo5pfod3bdg12d2llbh3g 200 0 0
```

Comment: Is Account set up as its own application?  That may cause an issue as the user is coming up a level which could mean crossing some kind of boundary, but that's just my guess at a quickie answer.

Comment: When you said  `is passing the correct username and password` you meant you could verify that password HASHES match correct? You should never be able to verify the passWORD is a match.

Comment: are you sure that URL is accessible on another device that isn't an ipad? IE that you are being bitten by your auth rules?

Comment: @JB, Chris and Adam: It is an intermittent fault.  Most of the time it works well, but occasionally fails on the iPad.  It works solidly on Chrome.  My investigations have led me to the IIS logs, where the cookie can be seen arriving but is obviously not being correctly interpreted. The url and password matching is working 'most of the time'.

Comment: Do you have any logic that redirects to a login page if the session (or some other context) isn't available?
If the cookie is getting sent over it should be correctly processed which then makes me wonder if something else isn't causing the redirect.

Comment: @Adam - there isn't any logic, but I did add some logging to the Application_OnAuthenticateRequest event in Global.asax.cs.  This seems to show that when the issue occurs then HttpContext.Current.User is null, whereas usually HttpContext.Current.User=System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal (i.e. when the error does not occur).

Comment: this is a single server right- not a load balanced scenario? Also - in that forms auth ticket do you store any custom information - roles, etc?

Comment: @Adam - yep, it is a single server.  There is role info in the auth ticket.

Comment: I have added two IIS log entries that reflect a successful login attempt

Comment: can you post a successful /ProfileList reference since I dont see any above?

Comment: @Adam - I've posted the IIS log entries for a successful login when trying to get to /ProfileList.  One further question - when you create your own auth ticket cookie, what increments the ticket expiry time?  Does ASP.NET do this automatically?  btw thanks very much for your help

Comment: asp.net does this automatically. but ONLY when half of the time has elapsed. Thats why I asked about session, since the session is updated on every request to extend by say.. 20 minutes (or whatever its set to). The forms auth ticket timeout only updates after half the time has elapsed (for performance reasons)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe I have the answer. You need to specifically set web.config to force the use of cookies. My authentication setting in web.config now looks like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" 
             cookieless="UseCookies" 
             />
    </authentication>
```

It is the cookieless="UseCookies" entry that solved the problem. The default value for this is UseDeviceProfile. It must have been the case that an iPad does not have a consistent UseDeviceProfile regime.  On the iPad, sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't.  Don't ask me why.  It now seems to be consistently working.

Comment: Thank you _so much_ for this. It's been driving me nuts. What's worse, I first noticed the problem while on vacation in Hawaii (and using the iPad more than normal). Once I noticed it it was hard to 'mentally put down' and enjoy the trip. I really hate bugs like this and it's great to cross it off the list :-)

Comment: Awesome. This one really helped me. Thanks a ton. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add I came across this problem in IE11. Any .net 4.0 app using forms authentication seems to get into an infinite redirect loop, must be something to do with the user agent.

The cookieless="UseCookies" config change also fixes the IE11 issue

Answer (score 0):

I've spent many hours on a similar issue with IE11 the other day and yes, the cookieless="UseCookies" seemed to have helped with the login ... but it didn't solve another problem ...

Turned out to be a problem with IIS 7 NOT recognizing IE11 as a modern browser and reverting its logic to a basic support with no cookies, no javascript support in the browser (IIS wouldn't send cookies or javascript code to the browser hence cookieless="UseCookies" would help with the cookies issue on login, but javascript was still a problem).

A solution I found was to add .browser definition files to my app's App_Browsers folder for FireFox and IE11 and I no longer needed the cookieless="UseCookies" option, at least for IE11

Unfortunately, I can't find any .browser files for the iPad and it seems one of my clients is having exactly the same issues as yours with their iPad... Perhaps someone else has found it and can share it here? If not, I'll keep trying to solve this and post my solution once I find it. Until then ... UseCookies must do.