# Form Cookie Expiring too soon on production server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

i have following settings in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/login"   
       slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880" protection="All" />
 </authentication>
```

but the cookie expires in less than five minutes of inactivity. Any clue on what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I recognize this behavior from a web host where I run one of my sites. It all started when moving to new servers, prepared for dotNET 4. The web.config is completely ignored and, as you mention, five minutes seems to be the break-point.

Your question made me start digging around, looking for a working. I started by browsing the [forms-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms-authentication) category here on Stackoverflow, one of the tags you used. After a few minutes I found a somewhat similar question: [ASP.NET forms authentication keeps displaying login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269079/asp-net-forms-authentication-keeps-displaying-login-page). In the accepted answer it was suggested to set `cookieless="UseCookies`.

I checked my own web.config and found that `cookieless` was left out, falling back on the default configuration. A quick edit and some testing gave a positive result. It worked great. But then I edited the file back, as it was before and have now had a working session for ten ours. I added a `meta-refresh` which reloaded the page every ten minutes. Perhaps the hosting company have tweaked some parameter. The sad thing is I have no solution for you :(

Instead of running your service in the web server shipped with with Visual Studio, try to run it locally in IIS and see if you can reproduce the issue.

(To help users answer this questions I guess it would help if you provide some info about the production server, component versions and stuff. Like which version of IIS you're running and which framework version you build for. And, when you run your site in test do you use IIS or the light-weight web server in Visual Studio?)

Comment: thnaks matpe. For testing i use built vs web server what kind of info about production server do u require?