# Request desktop site option on ipad chrome browser for an ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ipad, google-chrome, forms-authentication

What does "Request desktop site" mean on an iPad chrome browser and why does an ASP.NET website not work until this option is enabled?

If my site is loaded on iPad Chrome, the login does not work, instead it redirects to a strange URL.

[image]

If the user selects "Request desktop site", then the login works fine.  What can I add to my ASP.NET MVC site to change it so that the user does not have to click the "Request desktop site" option?

EDIT: Have just realized that the URL generated is because it is trying to use cookie-less forms authentication.  It must be that iPad Chrome by default does not accept cookies?

Comment: Looks like this might be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6292614/325727

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes a lot of people have reported that Chrome on iOS does not seem to accept cookies.  There are multiple ways to get around it, easiest is to force using of cookies in cookieless mode.

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="3600" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: +1 yes this looks like it is just a bug in ASP.NET's browser capabilities list, it doesn't think that iPad chrome allows cookies when of course it does.